# Using PROPS inside mounted() in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have props like below

```
props: ['applicants'],
```

I would like to use that props like below

```
methods : {
fetchapplicants() {
                let self = this;
                console.log(self.applicants.length);
            }
        },
mounted() {
     this.fetchapplicants();
}
```

I am getting output `undefined`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't need to use `self` from the code I see, there is no need for that. So, just do this.

```
methods : {
    fetchapplicants() {
        console.log(this.applicants.length);
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.fetchapplicants();
}
```

Also, make sure to pass props as objects, this is the recommended way and it will help you define the type and default value of the passed prop

```
props: {
    applicants: {
      type: Array,
      required: false, 
      default: []
    }
}
```

Last, make sure you are passing an array to your component. I think that may be the problem, so wherever in your code, when you call your components make sure to even test it by passing a default array as:

```
<my-component :applicants="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"></my-component>
```